# Execute a select query using while loop to get all row values and a calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that has client code, start date, end date and the client's performance between start and end dates. I now want to re-base these performance numbers to 100 to report them in a SSRS chart. It is easy to do this in excel but I don't want to create another field on the table and update all the rows with their respective re-based values. I have written the following block to run through SSRS report dataset and I get **'No data Found'** when I execute it. But there are 13 rows I need re-based for the client I'd chosen. Also I need the output in a queried format (like below) because the output is for a SSRS chart. Thanks.

```
    DECLARE 
    i FLOAT(126) :=100;
    rowno number :=1; 
    n NUMBER;
    clicode VARCHAR(10);
    startdate DATE;
    enddate DATE;  
    performance FLOAT(126);
    month VARCHAR(10);
    year VARCHAR(10);  
    rebased_perf FLOAT(126);        
    BEGIN 
    select count(*) into n from performance;             
    WHILE rowno <= n LOOP
    select a.*,i*(1+(a.performance/100)) as rebased_perf into rowno,clicode,startdate,enddate,performance,month,year,rebased_perf from 
    (select rownum ,b.* from 
    (select clicode,startdate,enddate,performance,month,year from performance
    where period='Halfyearly'
    and clicode='XXX004'
    order by enddate) b )a 
    where rownum=rowno;
    i:=rebased_perf;
    rowno:=rowno+1;
    END LOOP;
  END; 

 CLICODE       STARTDATE    ENDDATE     PERFORMANCE  REBASED_PERF
 Startbase     05-Oct-09                             100
 XXX004        05-Oct-09    05-Apr-10   3.85         103.85
 XXX004        05-Apr-10    05-Oct-10   0.63         104.50
 XXX004        05-Oct-10    05-Apr-11   4.58         109.29
 XXX004        05-Apr-11    05-Oct-11   -8.07        100.47
 XXX004        05-Oct-11    05-Apr-12   8.13         108.63
```

Comment: That code could use some formatting (indentation)!

Comment: This is my first try at using a loop, I'm sure it needs a lot of formatting

Comment: Do you have to use a loop (or PL/SQL more generally) for this? Is it part of your learning PL/SQL, loops, cursors etc.? If not a plain SQL solution will almost surely be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure SQL solution:

If you have more than one CLIcode in your data (you probably do or else you wouldn't have that column), it makes no sense to have a row that shows "startbase" instead of the CLIcode. The fact that it is the "base" can be seen in the NULLs in `enddate` and `performance`, and the 100 in growth_of_100. Also, I assume the first row is in your base data; it shouldn't be, and it can be produced from the other rows. Adapt as needed. Even if you need the output inside some application, it is still best to run the plain SQL query and only import its output to your application.

```
with
     test_data ( clicode, startdate, enddate, performance ) as (
       select 'XXX004', date '2009-10-05', null             ,  null from dual union all
       select 'XXX004', date '2009-10-05', date '2010-04-05',  3.85 from dual union all
       select 'XXX004', date '2010-04-05', date '2010-10-05',  0.63 from dual union all
       select 'XXX004', date '2010-10-05', date '2011-04-05',  4.58 from dual union all
       select 'XXX004', date '2011-04-05', date '2011-10-05', -8.07 from dual union all
       select 'XXX004', date '2011-10-05', date '2012-04-05',  8.13 from dual
     )
--
-- end of test data; actual query begins here
select clicode, startdate, enddate, performance, 
       round(100 * exp( sum( ln(1 + nvl(performance,0) / 100) ) over
           (partition by clicode order by enddate asc nulls first) ), 2) as growth_of_100
from test_data
order by clicode, enddate asc nulls first
;


CLICODE STARTDATE ENDDATE   PERFORMANCE GROWTH_OF_100
------- --------- --------- ----------- -------------
XXX004  05-Oct-09                              100.00
XXX004  05-Oct-09 05-Apr-10        3.85        103.85
XXX004  05-Apr-10 05-Oct-10        0.63        104.50
XXX004  05-Oct-10 05-Apr-11        4.58        109.29
XXX004  05-Apr-11 05-Oct-11       -8.07        100.47
XXX004  05-Oct-11 05-Apr-12        8.13        108.64

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks for that, didnt know I could do this just using SQL, on another note I added start-base just to make the calculation clear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `rownum` the way you want. You should rather use a cursor or implicit loop directly:

```
DECLARE 
  i FLOAT(126) :=100;
  rebased_perf FLOAT(126);        
BEGIN 
  for x in (
     select a.*,i*(1+(a.performance/100)) as rebased_perf from (
              select clicode,startdate,enddate,performance,month,year from performance 
               where period='Halfyearly' and clicode='XXX004') a 
            order by enddate
  ) loop
    -- no more "into" rowno,clicode,startdate,enddate,performance,month,year,rebased_perf 
    --- but you can address the fields with "x.<field>"
    i:=x.rebased_perf;
    dbms_output.put_line('i='||i);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I had to use the rownum because the re-basing has to be done in a particular order (in my case from Oct09 to Apr16), if the order gets mixed up I could get wrong performances. Also how can I get the result in a queried format as above. Thanks.

Comment: @danny, you should try `endate` outside the A table (I edited my answer) ; you should ask another question about that. And show your attempts. We won't do all the work for you. You are here to learn, aren't you?